# Remote nodes, group leaders and printouts

Tags: erlang

Given two Erlang nodes, "foo@host" and "bar@host", the following produces a print-out on "foo":

```
(foo@host) rpc:call('bar@host', io, format, ["~p", [test]]).
```

While the following prints out on "bar":

```
(foo@host) rpc:call('bar@host', erlang, display, [test]).
```

Even if `erlang:display/1` is supposed to be used for debug only, both functions are supposed to send stuff to the standard output. Each process should inherit the group leader from its parent, so I would expect that the two functions would behave in a consistent way.

Is there any rationale for the above behaviour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for this difference in behaviour is *where* and *by whom* the output is done:

- `erlang:display/1` is a *BIF* and is handled directly by the BEAM which writes it straight out to its standard output without going anywhere near Erlang's io-system. So doing this on `bar` results in it printed to `bar`'s standard output.
- `io:format/1/2` is handled by the Erlang io-system. As no `IoDevice` has been given it sends an io-request to its *group leader*. The `rpc:call/4` is implemented in such away that the remotely spawned process inherits the group leader of the process doing the RPC call. So the output goes to the standard output of the calling process. So doing an RPC call on `foo` to the node `bar` results in the output going to `foo`'s standard output.

Hence the difference. It is interesting to note that no special handling of this is needed in the Erlang io-system, once the group leader has been set it all works transparently.

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is also why erlang:display/1 is great for demonstrating how Erlang I/O works. Your exact example using rpc on a remote node with display or format is something I've used in training sessions. :-)

Comment: @RichardC You mean the difference between writing straight out to stdout and using the Erlang io?

Comment: Yep. The rpc doing display/1 prints its output on the remote node's terminal, while the one using io prints on the caller's terminal.